# Populate column based on "Select count(*) Group By"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a table in a stored procedure called @AccountStatRollup.  I populated it with AccountIDs.  I created a second table called @Contacts.  I populated it with ContactIDs and ContactAccountIDs.  I'm trying to populate the @AccountStatRollup.AccountContacts field with the total of related contacts from the @Contacts table.

I've tried a number if sql update statements and failed.  This is the last statement I tried:

Thanks for any help.

Kevin

```
Declare @AccountStatRollup TABLE(
    AccountID varchar(30),
    AccountContacts int
)
Declare @Contacts TABLE(
    ContactID varchar(30),
    ContactsAccountID varchar(30)
)
```

My attempt to calculate Account Contacts count

```
UPDATE @AccountStatRollup a 
    SET a.AccountContacts = (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM @Contacts c GROUP BY c.ContactsAccountID)
    ON c.ContactsAccountID = a.ContactID
```

Thanks everyone!
I managed to get this code to save and execute (Microsoft SQL server)

```
--Calculate Account Contacts count
    UPDATE @AccountStatRollup
    SET AccountContacts = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Contacts 
    WHERE ContactsAccountID = AccountID )
```

I let the stored procedure run for a little while then I killed it.  I'm realizing that this must be a very inefficient the way for me to count.  I was going to use this example to add other column totals as well.  I have maybe 30,000 accounts and 16,000 Contacts...

I tried to get this code working but it did not recognize c.ContactsAccountID, couldn't get around it.

```
--Calculate Account Contacts count ver 2      
    UPDATE a
    SET AccountContacts = c.cnt
    FROM @AccountStatRollup a join
         (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
          FROM @Contacts c
          GROUP BY c.ContactsAccountID
         ) c
         ON c.ContactsAccountID = a.AccountID;
```

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AccountStatRollup, Line 56
Invalid column name 'ContactsAccountID'.

Is there a more efficient way to calculate totals than what I tried?

Thanks!

## Kevin

OK, I figured out how to make this work fast.

I created my temp tables with unique indexes.

-- Create a local table to hold Account Stats
        Declare @AccountStatRollup TABLE(
            AccountID varchar(18),
            AccountContacts int,
            UNIQUE (AccountID)
        );

-- Create a local table to hold Contact data
        Declare @Contacts TABLE(
            ContactID varchar(18),
            ContactsAccountID varchar(18),
            UNIQUE (ContactID)
        );

-- Create a local table to hold Contact calculation data
        Declare @tmpAccountCalculation TABLE(
            AccountID varchar(18),
            AccountName varchar(100),
            FieldCount int,
            UNIQUE (AccountID)
        );

-- Populate @AccountStatRollup table with all AccountID values
        INSERT INTO @AccountStatRollup(AccountID)
            SELECT ID from sfAccount
-- Populate @Contacts table with all AccountID values
        INSERT INTO @Contacts(ContactID, ContactsAccountID)
            SELECT ID, ACCOUNTID from sfContact

-- Populate @tmpAccountCalculation table
        INSERT INTO @tmpAccountCalculation(AccountID, AccountName, FieldCount)
        SELECT dbo.sfAccount.ID, dbo.sfAccount.NAME, COUNT(dbo.sfContact.ACCOUNTID) AS  ContactCount
        FROM dbo.sfAccount INNER JOIN dbo.sfContact ON dbo.sfAccount.ID = dbo.sfContact.ACCOUNTID
        GROUP BY dbo.sfAccount.ID, dbo.sfAccount.NAME HAVING (COUNT(dbo.sfContact.ACCOUNTID) > 0)

-- Update the @AccountStatRollup table
        UPDATE  A
        SET A.AccountContacts = B.FieldCount
        FROM @AccountStatRollup A
        INNER JOIN @tmpAccountCalculation B ON A.AccountID = B.AccountID

-- Test the output
Select * from @AccountStatRollup where AccountContacts >0 Order by AccountContacts desc

This takes about 1 second to run.

Whew....

Kevin

Comment: Advice: if you store the count, it will have to be updated whenever the @Contacts table changes. Or it will have to be acceptable for it to be slightly wrong. Usually (but not always) it is better to count the number whenever you need it instead of storing it. Obviously performance and database load need to be taken into consideration, and may make storing it the better option.

Comment: The sql code works for this answer.  I just need to find a more efficient way to calc data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using table variables, I'm assuming that this is SQL Server.  You can do the update in a nifty way using `update` with `join` syntax:

```
UPDATE a
    SET AccountContacts = c.cnt
    FROM @AccountStatRollup a join
         (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
          FROM @Contacts c
          GROUP BY c.ContactsAccountID
         ) c
         ON c.ContactsAccountID = a.ContactID;
```

The SQL standard way, which should work in almost all databases, is to use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE @AccountStatRollup a 
    SET AccountContacts = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                           FROM @Contacts c
                           WHERE c.ContactsAccountID = a.ContactID
                          );
```

When you use the correlated subquery, the `group by` is not needed.  In fact, including a `group by` is misleading, because it suggests that there might be more than one group -- and that would cause an error when the statement is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the where condition to the inner query, and you don't need the group by:

```
UPDATE @AccountStatRollup a 
  SET
    a.AccountContacts = (
      SELECT
        COUNT(*)
      FROM
        @Contacts c
      where
        c.ContactsAccountID = a.ContactID
  );
```